# How can I tell spring security to apply authorizeRequests just for a specific port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, port

We configured our new micro service (using Spring-Boot) in a way that the official API is on port 8080 (which is be mapped outside of our virtual network to normal HTTPS on port 443), while some management functions are on a secondary HTTP port 7979. These are only used inside the virtual network, and used for monitoring, loadbalancing etc.

All API access needs to be secured with OAuth, while the management functions should be accessible freely inside the network. So we configured Spring security this way (http is a HttpSecurity object):

```
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/info").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/health").anonymous()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/warehouses/**").access(oauthScopeRead)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/warehouses/**").access(oauthScopeWrite)

            .anyRequest().denyAll();
```

This has the effect on both ports: `/info` and `/health` are unauthorized, while `/warehouses` needs authentication, and everything else also needs authentication (returns 401, but when invoking with authentication, it returns 403).

As there is no `/info` or `/health` on the public port, these return 404 for unauthorized users, while everything else returns 401. I'm unsatisfied with this and would like to have

- on the public port, require authentication for everything (and return 404 or 403 only after being authenticated)
- on the admin port, require no authentication at all (return 404 for everything which is not one of the configured endpoints).

I couldn't find anything about ports in the Spring Security Javadocs or [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

What can I do here?

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution:

The `authorizeRequests()` method here returns an `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry`, which has (from its ancestor class AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry) beside some `antMatchers` methods also a generic `requestMatchers()` method, which takes one or more `RequestMatcher` objects. It turns out this is an interface I can implement myself:

```
/**
 * A request matcher which matches just a port.
 *
 * @param   port  the port to match.
 *
 * @return  the new matcher.
 */
private RequestMatcher forPort(final int port) {
    return (HttpServletRequest request) -> port == request.getLocalPort();
}
```

(This is Java 8 syntax, with previous Java versions you'll had to write an anyonymous class here.)

While `requestMatchers` takes several such matchers, it looks like those are connected by OR (at least [this example suggests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--) this), thus I used an AndRequestMatcher to connect it to the matcher for the path (and HTTP method)).

The final code looked like this:

```
@Value("${management.port}")
private int managementPort;

@Value("${server.port}")
private int apiPort;

/**
 * Configure scopes for specific controller/httpmethods/roles here.
 */
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //J-
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(forPortAndPath(managementPort, "/info")).anonymous()
            .requestMatchers(forPortAndPath(managementPort, "/health")).anonymous()

            .requestMatchers(forPortAndPath(apiPort, HttpMethod.GET, "/warehouses/**")).access(oauthScopeRead)
            .requestMatchers(forPortAndPath(apiPort, HttpMethod.PUT, "/warehouses/**")).access(oauthScopeWrite)

            .anyRequest().denyAll();
    //J+
}

/**
 * Creates a request matcher which only matches requests for a specific local port and path (using an
 * {@link AntPathRequestMatcher} for the path part).
 *
 * @param   port         the port to match
 * @param   pathPattern  the pattern for the path.
 *
 * @return  the new request matcher.
 */
private RequestMatcher forPortAndPath(final int port, @Nonnull final String pathPattern) {
    return new AndRequestMatcher(forPort(port), new AntPathRequestMatcher(pathPattern));
}

/**
 * Creates a request matcher which only matches requests for a specific local port, path and request method (using
 * an {@link AntPathRequestMatcher} for the path part).
 *
 * @param   port         the port to match
 * @param   pathPattern  the pattern for the path.
 * @param   method       the HttpMethod to match. Requests for other methods will not be matched.
 *
 * @return  the new request matcher.
 */
private RequestMatcher forPortAndPath(final int port, @Nonnull final HttpMethod method,
        @Nonnull final String pathPattern) {
    return new AndRequestMatcher(forPort(port), new AntPathRequestMatcher(pathPattern, method.name()));
}

/**
 * A request matcher which matches just a port.
 *
 * @param   port  the port to match.
 *
 * @return  the new matcher.
 */
private RequestMatcher forPort(final int port) {
    return (HttpServletRequest request) -> { return port == request.getLocalPort(); };
}
```

*This does not fully reflect the question: the managementPort has here just "/info" and "/health" public reachable, instead of everything.*

*You could use this*

```
                 .requestMatchers(forPort(managementPort)).anonymous()
```

*to make this port fully unauthorized.*

Comment: I am still searching for the solution +1

Comment: Yes, I cheated a bit. I was typing the question, then (before submitting it) had an idea for the answer and tried it out before deciding to submit the question anyways. Then I just had to type the answer from the code I already had.

Comment: Good solution, didn't find a good way to test it with the server running on dynamic ports. I used `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` for my test classes, otherwise `private int apiPort` would just stay zero and I'd get 403 Forbidden at all my interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way to permit all access to management endpoints, regardless of which port they are running on:

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
    .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll();
```

The [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest#toAnyEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/servlet/EndpointRequest.html#toAnyEndpoint--) method returns a matcher that only matches actuator requests.

See [spring-boot-smoke-tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d42ad237f5a34d86bca39511be0ef67a7854656e/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-actuator-custom-security/src/main/java/smoketest/actuator/customsecurity/SecurityConfiguration.java#L57) for a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we don't want a "permit all" for all endpoints, as this defeats the purpose of having authorization at all.

Comment: EndpointRequest only matches actuator requests, not all requests (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/servlet/EndpointRequest.html#toAnyEndpoint--) - will add this clarification to the answer, since Spring's choice of class name is potentially confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Based in the previous answer I develop this class that excludes the admin port from the security. I hope this helps:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  /**
   * Puerto de administración por donde escucha Actuator.
   */
  @Value("${management.server.port}")
  private int managementPort;
  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
   * WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.
   * annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)
   */
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(forPort(managementPort));
  }
  /**
   * @param port
   *          Puerto que se desea comparar con el puerto de la respuesta http.
   * @return Verdadero si el puerto de la respuesta http es igual al puerto
   *         especificado.
   */
  private RequestMatcher forPort(int port) {
    return (HttpServletRequest request) -> {
      return port == request.getLocalPort();
    };
  }
}
```